# Treating a nested struct of the same leaf type as an array

Tags: rust

In C, I can take a `struct` like `figure` here:

```c
struct point
{
    int x, y;
};

struct box
{
    struct point left_top, right_bottom;
};

struct figure
{
    struct point points[100];
    struct box bounding_box;
};
```

and just treat it as an `int` array, which is very convenient in some cases. I wonder if Rust offers any similar facilities? If not for directly treating a nested `struct` as an array, then just for iteration? (For example, what if I wanted to increment all of the `ints` by 1?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For obvious reasons this requires `unsafe` but sure it can be done:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: usize,
    y: usize,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Box {
    left_top: Point,
    right_bottom: Point,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Figure {
    points: [Point; 5],
    bounding_box: Box,
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = Figure {
        points: [
            Point { x: 1, y: 2 },
            Point { x: 3, y: 4 },
            Point { x: 5, y: 6 },
            Point { x: 7, y: 8 },
            Point { x: 9, y: 10 },
        ],
        bounding_box: Box {
            left_top: Point { x: 11, y: 12 },
            right_bottom: Point { x: 13, y: 14 }
        },
    };

    assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<[usize;14]>(), std::mem::size_of::<Figure>());

    let g: &mut [usize; 14] = unsafe { &mut *(&mut f as *mut Figure).cast() };
    for l in g {
        *l += 1;
    }

    dbg!(f);
}
```

Of course usually you would want to hide that away behind a safe abstraction such as `AsRef` or `AsMut`:

```rust
impl AsRef<[usize; 14]> for Figure {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[usize; 14] {
        assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<[usize;14]>(), std::mem::size_of::<Figure>());
        unsafe { &*(self as *const Figure).cast() }
    }
}

impl AsMut<[usize; 14]> for Figure {
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [usize; 14] {
        assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<[usize;14]>(), std::mem::size_of::<Figure>());
        unsafe { &mut *(self as *mut Figure).cast() }
    }
}
```

Note that without `#[repr(C)]` the compiler is free to arrange the fields however (order, padding) it likes and thus this code would be UB.

Answer (score 2):

The [bytemuck](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/) library provides a fully safe way to convert between any structure made of integers (or other types which may contain arbitrary bytes). Simply add

```rust
#[derive(bytemuck::Zeroable, bytemuck::Pod)]
```

and you can use bytemuck's safe `cast` functions to convert between your type and arrays or any type that implements `Pod` and is of the same length. Here is a modification of cafce25's example code to use `bytemuck` instead of an unsafe pointer conversion:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, bytemuck::Zeroable, bytemuck::Pod)]
struct Point {
    x: usize,
    y: usize,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, bytemuck::Zeroable, bytemuck::Pod)]
struct Box {
    left_top: Point,
    right_bottom: Point,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, bytemuck::Zeroable, bytemuck::Pod)]
struct Figure {
    points: [Point; 5],
    bounding_box: Box,
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = Figure {
        points: [
            Point { x: 1, y: 2 },
            Point { x: 3, y: 4 },
            Point { x: 5, y: 6 },
            Point { x: 7, y: 8 },
            Point { x: 9, y: 10 },
        ],
        bounding_box: Box {
            left_top: Point { x: 11, y: 12 },
            right_bottom: Point { x: 13, y: 14 }
        },
    };

    let g: &mut [usize; 14] = bytemuck::cast_mut::<Figure, [usize; 14]>(&mut f);
    for l in g {
        *l += 1;
    }

    dbg!(f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Does the compiler give an error if you type, say, `15` instead of `14`?

Comment: @MWB unfortunately, size mismatches will produce a *run-time* error. But that is addressable by having a unit test for any code that uses a cast — it will either always succeed, if the size matches, or always fail. You can also cast to a slice instead of an array; then the only error case would be is if the struct size is not a multiple of size_of usize.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @cafce25's unsafe solution, you can do iteration in completely safe code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn pts_ints_mut(pts: &mut [Point]) -> impl '_ + Iterator<Item = &mut i32> {
    pts.iter_mut()
        .flat_map(|pt| [&mut pt.x, &mut pt.y])
        //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //             must specify all ints in `Point`

}


fn main() {
    let mut pts = [
        Point { x: 1, y: 2 },
        Point { x: 3, y: 4 },
    ];
    
    println!("{pts:?}"); // [Point { x: 1, y: 2 }, Point { x: 3, y: 4 }]
    
    // get iterator of mutable references to each integer
    pts_ints_mut(&mut pts)
        // do something with that iterator
        .for_each(|n| *n += 1);
        
    println!("{pts:?}"); // [Point { x: 2, y: 3 }, Point { x: 4, y: 5 }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although it's not clear how composable this approach is (when you have a nested hierarchy of structs)

Comment: Also I wonder if one of the serialization libraries can be piggybacked here.